# Fatal error: Call to undefined function bccomp()

Tags: php, bcmath

I am getting this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function bccomp()

I am using Ubuntu, and I installed PHP-5.6 using APT-GET command

Comment: is bcmath extension enabled?

Comment: See [this reference answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12784048#12784048).

Comment: this will solve the problem apt install php5.6-bcmath, thank you all

Answer (score 16):

`bccomp()` function belongs to [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) package; if it's undefined, apparently, there's something wrong with the package itself. To be more specific, it's not enabled (as since PHP 4.0.4, libbcmath is bundled with PHP).

Quoting [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php):

> These functions are only available if PHP was configured with
>   `--enable-bcmath`.
>
> The Windows version of PHP has built-in support for this extension.
>   You do not need to load any additional extensions in order to use
>   these functions.

Comment: And of course, if you are on a new computer with Ubuntu. ensure you _install_ the package, e.g. `sudo apt install php-bcmath`

Comment: best is to install the bcmath extension with the php version number. `sudo apt install php7.x-bcmath`. and restart the service. `service apache2 restart`