# Undefined Function bcsub()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Im Using This Code In my Local Laravel and in success

```
public function dateForHuman($custom_timestamp) 
  {
        $date = bcsub($custom_timestamp, 25569, 10) * 86400;
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
  }
```

but When i try in my server, respond error Undefined Function bcsub()

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44049872/1427878

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP, Call to undefined function bccomp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049812/php-call-to-undefined-function-bccomp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to PHP documentation, BCMath is not available by default with PHP7 on Linux servers.**

*bcmath ist not installed automatically with php 7 on linux (ubuntu server) You have to use: sudo apt-get install php-bcmath*

**Please install it using apt-get:** `sudo apt-get install php-bcmath`

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php

Comment: if im using windows ?

Comment: please give upvote this answer if its help to you thank you !!! @RaihanAnubhawaEkaPutra